# Polymer starter kit unit testing

Tags: gulp, polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit, web-component-tester

I'm trying out polymer-starter-kit for the first time. Using yeoman generator I have scaffolded the basic project. When I run the unit test using Web Component Tester, am getting the following error.

Error: Could not request headers from http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.47/IEDriverServer_x64_2.46.0.zip

Following is the stdout when I run `gulp test:local`

> [12:39:44] Using gulpfile
>   ~\tryout\js\polymer\admin-portal-client\gulpfile.js [12:39:44]
>   Starting 'wct:local'... Starting Selenium server for local browsers
>
> ### ---------- selenium-standalone installation starting
>
> --- selenium install: from: http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.47/selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar
>   to:
>   C:\Users\ninpv1\tryout\js\polymer\admin-portal-client\node_modules\web-component-tester\node_modules\wct-local\node_modules\selenium-standalone.selenium\se
>   lenium-server\2.47.1-server.jar
>   --- chrome install: from: http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.16/chromedriver_win32.zip
>   to:
>   C:\Users\ninpv1\tryout\js\polymer\admin-portal-client\node_modules\web-component-tester\node_modules\wct-local\node_modules\selenium-standalone.selenium\ch
>   romedriver\2.16-x64-chromedriver
>   --- ie install: from: http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.47/IEDriverServer_x64_2.46.0.zip
>   to:
>   C:\Users\ninpv1\tryout\js\polymer\admin-portal-client\node_modules\web-component-tester\node_modules\wct-local\node_modules\selenium-standalone.selenium\ie
>   driver\2.46.0-x64-IEDriverServer.exe
>   --- File from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.16/chromedriver_win32.zip
>   has already been downloaded
>   --- File from http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.47/selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar
>   has already been downloaded [12:40:10] 
>   **'wct:local' errored after 26 s**
>   **[12:40:10] Error: Could not request headers from
>   http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.47/IEDriverServer_x64_2.46.0.zip:**

Node version : v0.12.7
npm version : 2.11.3
OS : Windows 7

What could be wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Because this file http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.47/IEDriverServer_x64_2.46.0.zip doesn't exist on that link. Just try to browse it on your browser on all 3 files. You will find this is the only one that doesn't exist. However, http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.47/IEDriverServer_x64_2.47.0.zip does exist.

Update: Looks like someone already opened an issue.
https://github.com/Polymer/web-component-tester/issues/206

Comment: Issue was because of a typo. It's closed in latest polymer commit.